Designing a flexible webhook class mapping
I'm trying to find the best way to map webhooks to one entity which i want to save in database.
Paypal offer many webhooks like order.checkout.approved or payment.capture.completed. They have same base of webhook and then diffrent 'resource' class.
For example i want to have entity Webhook where i want to save:
webhook.payerEmail.
For order.checkout.approved it would be json path:
{"resource": ..., "purchase_units": [  ..., "payee": { "email_address": "merchant@example.com"}]}
c# object
orderCheckoutApproved.resource.purchase_units.First().payee.email_address;
For payment.capture.completed it would be json path:
{"resource": {..., "seller_receivable_breakdown": { "platform_fees" : {..., ""payee": "email_address": "merchant@example.com"}"}}
c# object
paymentCaptureCompleted.resource.seller_receivable_breakdown.platform_fees.payee.email_address;
I know there is a simple way to switch case on webhook event type and then fill main entity with actual webhook fields, but i'm looking for a better solution.

It's unclear to me what is being asked here. Are you asking how to design your entities/database tables? Or simply how you map one data type to another? For the latter, maybe a library like AutoMapper can help. Try to update the question with the concrete problem you're trying to solve and maybe an example of what you've tried already. See [ask] for help.
